# NPM Installation on windows

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp

I am trying to install [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) on `Windows`, I first installed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then I executed `npm install`

1. First time l got  registry error parsing json

Now on version 8, I'm getting:

> npm ERR! code E404
>   npm ERR! 404 Not Found: bootstrap-sass@^3.0.0

May l please be assisted

Comment: Windows 1? Is this a new version of operating system?

Comment: How did you proceed to install npm ?
which command do you execute ?

Answer (score 2):

Please run

```
npm i --save bootstrap-sass
```

Comment: Now l just tried again and got npm ERR! 404 Not Found: gulp@^3.9.1

Comment: so ... npm i --save gulp etc

Comment: I tried that immediately after, and l am still getting a 404 error. Thank you for assisting,here is the detailed error message:                                                                            npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: gulp@^3.9.1

Comment: Please try npm install gulp-cli -g npm or install gulp -D

Comment: Eventually l did this to get it working: npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy